# trying to install Sitecore instance getting failed in all 8.2, 9.2 and 10.2 giving same error failed to start MicrosoftMarketingAutomationService

Tags: installation, sitecore

Hi have tried all the solutions in google for the this error nothing worked opened the IIS and checked the Xconnect is stopped while the installation is in process. after installation failure opened the Xconnect url from IIS found that the error is related to System.Memory.dll 4.5.5.0 version reference tried different solutions nothing worked. installation failing at step 68.

Error message:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Screenshots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvbbI.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WoCt.png)

Comment: There's a sitecore stack exchange https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the error means that the DLL does not exist in your web root:

```
c:/inetpub/wwwroot/[webroot]
```

In your webroot can you:

1. Look in your `bin` folder and see whether the `System.Memory.dll` exists?
2. Also. check your `web.config` file, and specifically the assemblies section and make sure that the `System.Memory.dll` version name and number is referenced correctly.

Comment: hi @iwa I have the system.memory dll in bin folder of web root and even I have changed the version in the webconfig and all other files where I have this assembly. the error is same. And I am not getting this error after installation. I got this error while installing the sitecore and installation not getting successfull.

Comment: @harshasaikumarSai - When you installed Sitecore OOTB did you get the default page display? If yes, did you then publish your project root to your web root? Try going to your project solution right find the System.Memory dll inside the bin directory. Right click on it and publish to web root.

Comment: I didn't get the default page display because the installation is failing.

Comment: @harshasaikumarSai - Are you installing Sitecore with the pop-up menu options?

Comment: I am Installing using Powershell script

Comment: Hi @harshasaikumarSai - try to install using the GUI/Pop default menu options. I find that way to be a little more straight forward.